# How do I render wsdl with xsd extensions in react js with the information like operation method sample request and sample response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl file which has reference to multiple xsd files in nested folder system .
I want to parse it and show on the ui with react js library

I tried few libraries with node but it hits actual backend and doesn't give parsed evelope

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.